# How to get the size in pixels of the Resize Corners of a Window

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a way (API) of getting the size (vertical and horizontal) in pixels of the resize corners?

I am referring to the area at each of the corners of a window where you can resize the window in both directions (Left-to-Right and Top-to-Bottom) at the same time using your mouse. You will know you are there with your mouse cursor when you hover over the corners of the window and the mouse cursor is a Diagonal Resizing cursor.

Thank you

Edit:
An example: Hover your mouse over the right edge of a sizable window. Start in the middle (vertically) of the window and move the mouse up along the edge until the horizontal sizing cursor changes to a diagonal sizing cursor. How do I determine by asking the OS how far that position when the cursor changes, is from the top of the window.

Comment: What is the underlying problem that made you come up with the solution of _"I need to get the resize border pixel size"_? Are you trying to capture resize events, and isn't there a different (read: easier) way to do that?

Comment: It is baked in the default window procedure if the app doesn't override the WM_NCHITTEST processing.  On Win8 it looks like 2x the border height and 1x the border width.  The real border size, not the one that Aero lies.

Comment: @CodeCaster. I want to simulate the behaviour of top-level windows inside a window with controls that I create. I want them to have the exact same behaviour when it comes to resizing and I do not want to try and get the info from an existing window. I prefer to get the size from some API or combined API calls. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: @Hans. I am struggling to understand exactly what you mean by "It is baked in the default window procedure". Is it something that I can intercept or read in some way? "looks like 2x the border height and 1x the border width"... In Win7 it also does seem so but it stays the same even if the borderwidth (SM_CYSIZEFRAME) is changed.

Comment: @BlurrySterk: Your comment "I do not want to get the info from an existing window" is entirely contradictory to the question you asked.  Perhaps you should ask a new question.

Comment: To be clear: "What size hotspots should I use for a window I will be creating in the future?" is a different question from "How can I get the size of the hotspots of a window?"  You asked the second, but the answer to the first would involve Microsoft UI design guidance more than calling any function.

Comment: In fact, the ability to have this resizing functionality for child windows already exists, it is used for MDI (Multiple Document Interface).  So there is no need to simulate it.

Comment: @Ben. Firstly MDI imposes certain limitations/functionalities which I do not want. I an doing this in a way to provide a system that I want.

Comment: @Ben. MDI imposes a limitation/functionality which I do not want. I am doing this in a way to provide a system that I want. Secondly while I appreciate the effort you have put into providing me with your insight I would have to say it seems that you are splitting hairs. I have explained in as much detail as I could and I have also said by comment that I wish not to get info from an existing window and if that does not satisfy you then I apoligize. You are welcome to not comment anymore if you feel that the way that I posted my existing question subtracts from that which I am asking advice for.

Comment: @BlurrySterk: I'm suggesting that you consider this question was valuable to you in that it helped you clarify your requirements and description thereof, and now you ask a new question which clearly expresses what you want.  Changing the meaning of a question mid-stream is frowned on.  You have to understand that the purpose of SO is to build a useful database of questions and answers, not specifically to help you.  There are now answers to the question you did ask, whether or not it's what you meant, which are probably useful to future visitors who find this question.

Comment: @Ben. Accepted. This post has been extremely helpful and I have learned so much from it. So now, how do I fix this post to reflect what you feel as necessary to convey the true request and then the correlating answers?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the size of the scrollbars. Call GetSystemMetrics with SM_CYHSCROLL and SM_CXVSCROLL. May be also SM_CYSIZEFRAME and SM_CXSIZEFRAME sizes can be combined.

But I think a better value is to use the height of the status bar. However even Microsoft Windows seems to use some fixed value as can seen on the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I see that your window has a SizeGrip. If you are referring to that then it is not what I require. It is the size of the resize corners in all four corners of the window. Have a look at my edit in my post. Yes, the size of the scrollbar would have been sufficient if I was looking for the SizeGrip size. If I cannot find a definite answer to my specific question then I suppose a workaround would force me to consider the scrollbar size. Thanks for that one.

Comment: I think what your are looking for is SM_CXSIZEFRAME and SM_CYSIZEFRAME. The surface of the corners is calculated by SM_CXSIZEFRAME * SM_CYSIZEFRAME in this case (if you ignore the size grip as additional diagonal sizing area).

Comment: In Windows 7 the Vertical pixel size of the sizing corner is 8 pixels and the horizontal is about double that. And that stays the same irrespective of changes to the borderwidth (SM_CYSIZEFRAME) and caption height (SM_CYCAPTION). As I mentioned to Ben Voight in WinXP it ranges between 25 and 27 in both directions but never leaves that range. So if there is no absolute pattern for theme enabled windows then it might differ between future Windows versions which it has between WinXP and Win7 and thus I cannot make assumptions and an API or SysMetric will make sure I keep to the norm of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the results of `GetClientRect` and `GetWindowRect` will tell you how wide the non-client (border) area is along each edge of the window.

If you're concerned that it might not all be active for sizing (true especially along the top), or you want to distinguish the diagonal sizing areas from edge sizing areas, you can take the coordinates discovered in step 1 and pass them to `SendMessage(WM_NCHITTEST)`  See [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618.aspx) for the various return codes.  There's no problem sending this message repeatedly -- it's designed to be called for each mouse move event and therefore is very fast.

Comment: @BlurrySterk: The size of the non-client area isn't the answer to your question... it's a way to get interesting values to query using `WM_NCHITTEST` which actually does answer your question.  `WM_NCHITTEST` tells you exactly how much of the non-client area is sizing borders and what part of the sizing border is a corner vs edge resize.

Comment: If you are referring to getting the Non-Client area by using GetClientRect and GetWindowRect; The size of the corners are not related to the Non-Client area unless themes are disabled in which case it is exactly the SM_CYSIZEFRAME + SM_CYCAPTION via GetSystemMetrics. With Themes enabled it has a minimum value if the caption height goes towards small and then it has a maximum if the caption height goes towards large. For instance in Windows XP even if you set the caption height anywhere from 25 to 50 the corner size will stay at 27. At its minimum it will be at 25. Also...

Comment: I want to simulate the behaviour of top-level windows inside a window with controls that I create. I want them to have the exact same behaviour when it comes to resizing and I do not want to try and get the info from an existing window. I prefer to get the size from some API or combined API calls. That is why I asked this question. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Wouldn't WM_NCHITTEST require a repetition to acquire what I am looking for if you do not consider where the mouse currently is?

Comment: @BlurrySterk: I already addressed that in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: If WM_NCHITTEST is used; unless I am mistaken the control that I am drawing to simulate the behaviour of a top-level window (is not one itself and also does not have a sizable border) will not be receiving the message. It needs to check against a window with a sizable border and that will most probably be a parent top-level window or another top-level window. Am I correct?

Comment: @BlurrySterk: Your question says you're trying to get these measurements on a window, I therefore assume that you have a handle to the window you're trying to measure.

Comment: It is actually how I percieve WM_NCHITTEST to work. I would prefer not to get any measurements from any window because the control will be dynamically created in different parents at different times. I would also prefer to rather call an API and just get the sizes that the OS uses. I am only investigating WM_NCHITTEST to get an understanding of it to see if it will be the answer for me if my required method fails. Just to cover my bases. "I therefore assume that you have a handle to the window you're trying to measure"... That is the reason for my previous comment question.